# Grabbing values from 3 arrays so it can be used in a ForEach

Tags: arrays, swiftui

I have three arrays and I want to grab from all of them to display to the user. When I had two arrays I found this code below and it worked fine

```
            List(Array(zip(book.words, book.definitions)), id: \.self.0) { (word, definition) in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(word) - \(definition)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        textToSpeech(word)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "speaker.3")
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
```

I cannot add another array to it though, because it is not allowed. I tried to base it off of the count in an array because they are all the same size.

```
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< book.words.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(book.words[index]) (\(book.partOfSpeech[index])) - \(book.definitions[index])")
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
    //                        print("hello")
                            textToSpeech(book.words[index])
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "speaker.3")
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
```

However I get this for an error

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
2021-07-19 19:43:31.572442-0700 SQLBook[61246:3585835] Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

The variable book is a class and it is passed in and decorated with an @ObservedObject. I am unsure if what I am trying to do is possible, because I have seen people ask this question and never got a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are dealing with array it is best to check the index you want to use is present.
I suspect that you 3 arrays are not of the same size. I tested your code successfully with the following test:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var book = BookModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(book: book)
        }
    }
}

class BookModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var words = ["word1","word2","word3"]
    @Published var partOfSpeech = ["pos1","pos2","pos3"]
    @Published var definitions = ["def1","def2","def3"]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var book: BookModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading ){
            if (book.words.count == book.partOfSpeech.count && book.words.count == book.definitions.count) {
                List {
                    ForEach(book.words.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(book.words[index]) (\(book.partOfSpeech[index])) - \(book.definitions[index])")
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                textToSpeech(book.words[index])
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "speaker.3")
                            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text("arrays not the same size") // show somehting else
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textToSpeech(_ word: String) {
        print("---> in textToSpeech word: " + word)
    }
}
```